# Synchronous video sampling in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video, sampling

I am trying to sample a video in HTML5.

The issue is next:
Setting `video.currentTime` while in a loop executes too fast for capturing the frame, because the frame is updated relatively slow. I got over this problem by setting interval of 150ms for each sampling.

Is there a way to create a loop to sample it without an interval? (I'm sampling an HD video right now and the rate of 150ms might be unnecessarily slow for smaller videos)

Comment: im guessing this might help you(i havent personally looked at the source) http://www.barbafan.de/html5video?video=tron

Comment: @rambocoder Actually, a very interesting link! Thanks. But... My issue is a bit different. The loop I'm talking about is executed before a single frame is changed, so I sample the same image all over the loop. This link talks about post-processing the frame. Anyway, as soon as I finish here - this will be the next challenge.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an event listener for the `seeked` event to know when the video has changed position.  I'd also recommend using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`, because that will ensure that any read events are synced with video frame updates.

```
videoElement.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
    console.log('current time has successfully been changed.');
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        // new frame to sample *should* now be available
        // you could test by comparing videoElement.currentTime against
        // last time you sampled.
    });
});
```